# agregar datos desde la base de datos al combobox

Tags: javafx

hola estoy tratando de seleccionar los datos de la tabla genero con la consulta `select sexo from genero` en un combobox, pero el combobox no me devuelve nada, este es el codigo que tengo el cual es el siguiente.

```
public void llenadocombobox() {
        Connection conn=null;
        ObservableList <String> listacombo= FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        String consulta = "select sexo from genero";
        try {

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-4JA6SFR:1433;databaseName=prueba", "sa", "123");
            Statement ps =conn.createStatement();
             ResultSet rs =ps.executeQuery(consulta);

            while(rs.next()) {

                listacombo.add(rs.getString("sexo"));


            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        combo.getItems().addAll(listacombo);
    }
```

declaro un `observablelist` para guardar los datos y luego mostrarlos en el combobox. alguna ayuda seria genial. gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Para este caso no es necesario esta variable:

```
ObservableList <String> listacombo= FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

puedes hacer la actualizacion del combobox de manera simple y dinámica

```
// patrones es una instancia de ComboBox<String> patrones;
patrones.getItems().addAll("XML Clientes -> ",
                               "XML Proveedores ->",
                               "XML Complementos ->",
                               "XML SAT -> revisar"
                               );
```